# Use jsoup to encode Html characters

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I have to encode characters to Html:

```
< to &lt;
> to &gt;
' to &#39;
" to &quot;
& to &amp;
```

I look for a utility function like [htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) in PHP:

```
String htmlspecialchars(String inputText)
```

Is it possible to use JSoup to encode these characters?

(I have found [htmlEscape](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/web/util/HtmlUtils.html#htmlEscape%28java.lang.String%29) in the Spring framework, but I don't want to use the Spring framework just for this simple function.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSoup is a library to parse the HTML.

I dont think you can use it to encode special characters into HTML.

The best way to do it, is to write your own method. Simply you can grab this method from Spring and you dont need to setup whole framework. See [source code](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/org/springframework/spring/2.0.4/spring-2.0.4-sources.jar!/org/springframework/web/util/HtmlUtils.java?format=ok).

Comment: Ok, I will use the source from Spring (which seems to be based on the Jakarta Commons Lang and its StringEscapeUtils class). (I just thought I can also use JSoup to encode characters because I need the JSoup JAR also for other tasks in my project.

Answer (score 10):

Apache Commons has StringEscapeUtils and it has escapeHtml method.

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils;

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String strHTMLInput = "<P>MyName<P>";
        String strEscapeHTML = StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(strHTMLInput);
        String strUnEscapeHTML = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml(strEscapeHTML);
        System.out.println("Escaped HTML >>> " + strEscapeHTML);
        System.out.println("UnEscaped HTML >>> " + strUnEscapeHTML);
    }
}
```

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0500__Apache-Common/StringEscape.htm

Comment: Thanks that would also work. I think that also future versions of the famous Google Guava will have Escaper-classes.

Answer (score 4):

If you have already JSoup on the classpath, just use `org.jsoup.nodes.Entities#escape(java.lang.String)`

Answer (score 2):

You can fake it with Jsoup, but I'm sure the other solutions are more thorough and probably less wasteful.  You could use some variant of this:

```
public static String escapeHtml(String text) {
    return (new TextNode(text, "")).toString();
}
```

With this,

```
System.out.println(HtmlUtils.escapeHtml("I <don't> \"want\" to see &s and >s."));
```

yields:

```
I &lt;don't&gt; "want" to see &amp;s and &gt;s.
```

You'll note the question marks are not escaped.