# html in text area -> from db -> java -> browser, edit and back

Tags: javascript, jsp, jakarta-ee, urlencode

I have html in my db, would like it to be editable in a text area in the CSR/ admin page.

Using java/ jsp would like to know if the following are a good way/ is there a better:
1. [apache commons StringEscapeUtils](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9462623/use-jsoup-to-encode-html-characters) to encode the data being sent to the browser. Plan to write out the string as a java script variable and then decode it and set it to the textarea's value. Want to do this so if a user enters
     as part of the value it does not close the textarea the next time its edited.

2. what do i use to unescape the data from StringEscapeUtils? (in javascript so the user sees the html and can edit in the textarea)
3. am i better of writing a simple replaceall using String to replace characters < > ? and then javascript to string functions to unescape them again ? If so do I need to unescape any other characters?

Any other pointers will be great.

Using java 6 with jboss 4.2 Will take care of the collation / format in db saw other threads about that.

**UPDATE:**
Ended up using this - can be improved

```
public static String screenHtmlShow(String s){
    s= s.replace("<","< ");
    s= s.replace("/>","/ >");
    s= s.replace("\n"," ");
    s= s.replace("\r"," ");
    s= s.replace("\"","'");
    return s;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `<c:out value="${value}"/>` on the JSP page. It has an attribute `escapeXml=true/false` which could be useful as well.

Comment: thanks I dont have tag libs, but i had a look at the code in wiki and wrote my own function :-) thing is i needed to un-escape within the page and show a preview - just like a wiki ...